Laravel 11 Invalid datetime format when seeding
Hie. I have not used seeders in a long time and in my Laravel project I just started I am getting an error. The below is the seeder class. The factory is working with no issues though.
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $users = [
            ['name' => 'Admin', 'username' => 'admin', 'status' => 'active', 'role' => 'admin',  'email' => 'admin@test.com', 'password' => Hash::make('password')],
            ['name' => 'Vendor', 'username' => 'vendor', 'status' => 'active', 'role' => 'vendor',  'email' => 'vendor@test.com', 'password' => Hash::make('password')],
            ['name' => 'User', 'username' => 'user', 'status' => 'active', 'role' => 'user',  'email' => 'user3@test.com', 'password' => Hash::make('password')],
        ];

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            User::create($user);
        }
    }
}


My user model:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
            'password' => 'hashed',
        ];
    }
}

I tried passing the date times into the arrays as
`$now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();`

And
`$now = Carbon::now();`

but no luck. The below is the screenshot of the error:
Seeder Run Code

Is there any error you are getting ?what $now prints?
How did you execute this seeder class I am asking because there are so many way.

You need to post the failing code, the seeder you posted doesnt have any datetime columns.

in the example datetime you posted you are using backticks, these are not single-quotes! https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

before using the create method, you will need to specify either a fillable in model, try use the insert() or in model $fillable add the dates

Share migration file for users table and it seemed from your shared error image that you have defined incorrect data-type for username column of users table.Also as mentioned in the above comment put a protected $fillable option in your user model.

assuming you are trying to set email_verified_at as your code isnt clear.
You will need to do the following.
    $users = [
            ['name' => 'Admin', 'username' => 'admin', 'status' => 'active', 'role' => 'admin',  'email' => 'admin@test.com', 'password' => Hash::make('password'), 'email_verified_at' => now()],
            ['name' => 'Vendor', 'username' => 'vendor', 'status' => 'active', 'role' => 'vendor',  'email' => 'vendor@test.com', 'password' => Hash::make('password'), 'email_verified_at' => now()],
            ['name' => 'User', 'username' => 'user', 'status' => 'active', 'role' => 'user',  'email' => 'user3@test.com', 'password' => Hash::make('password'), 'email_verified_at' => now()],
    ];

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        User::create($user);
    }

Also its worth looking at laravels model factories, simplifies this a bit and makes it a lot more debuggable.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-factories
